# Simple Update to MySQL with PHP Object Oriented Programming

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am doing an update into mysql but would like to do this in OOP instead of the procedural method. How can I update with OOP? I am first testing that there is data to update in the input. Check to see if it is empty. Then I take that result and store it into a variable and then I query the database to update the column, I then submit the image file to the correct folder. Below is the code I am working with. I keep getting a blank page. I don't get any error messages to see where I am going wrong. I have tried a few different modifications but none are working.

```
    if(!empty($_FILES['logo']) && !empty($_FILES['logoalt'])) { 

        // Testing the connection to MySQL either send message or query MySQL for table creation

    if($DB->connect_errno){
        printf("Could not connect to MySQL Database: %s \n",$DB->connect_error);
        exit();
    } else{

        $DB = new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

            $logo = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
            $logoalt = $_POST['logoalt'];

        if($DB->query("UPDATE HomePageData SET Logo = '$logo', ImgAlt = 'logoalt'")) {

        foreach($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array) {
            if(is_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'])) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'],
                    "$file_dir/".$file_array['name'])
                        or die ("Couldn't move file");  
                            echo "<p>Your data was successfully submitted</p>"; 
            } else {
                printf("Could not load file: %s \n",$DB->error);
            }
        }
        $DB->close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to turn errors on at the top of the page: `ini_set("display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Then you will probably see the errors.

Comment: try using echo & die to debug the problem. Also try following MVC pattern

Comment: Also, you are using your $DB before defining your $DB variable. That is likely the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

Object oriented style

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Procedural style

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

> How can I update with OOP?

You are already. So when instantiating/creating a new object with

```
$DB = new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
```

outlines the usage of *Object oriented style*.

> I keep getting a blank page. I don't get any error messages to see where I am going wrong.

This is not title related - for the very trivial solution I would suggest to turn on [error displaying](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); //should be used in development environment
ini_set('display_errors', true); //should be used in development environment
```